# Setting static ip causes network delays

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, static-ip

I am running into a problem after setting static IP on my linux systems  (Ubuntu and Raspbian).

If i set static ip, i experience 5-10 second initial hangs when interacting with it by SSH or http **after being left inactive for a few seconds**

This does not happen when using dhcp.

- ensured no conflicting ips
- tried turning of power management settings
- using wired lan

Comment: Do you have any events around that time in the systemd journal? `sudo journalctl --follow --lines=100 --no-tail`

Comment: I started that and then waited for it to occur, but there was no new logs at all in the journalctl

Comment: You can use a network packet capture with `tcpdump -w dropped_connections.pcap -i ethX not port 22` and open it with Wireshark on your machine to analyze it. If there is nothing confidential in your network traffic you can share the capture with us.

Comment: Hi @MirceaVutcovici

- I have launched a server on port 80.
- started capture on port 80.
- After issue occured, stopped the capture.

I dont know how to interpret these results, so here is the capture: 
https://file.io/a4HtODgL

Comment: The capture isn't available on that site anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the probable cause of issue,
I tried to install netsniff-ng and somehow its installation removed
the lagging, and the only notable change was that
Systemd-timesyncd was removed, i am investigating
how this is related to my network problem.